# Perl code to refer to multiple file of the same extension (.xml)

Tags: perl, xml

I'm trying to parse multiple xml files but i'm a bit stuck with something. The  `$twig->parsefile("output_1.xml");`   section of the below script works fine in parsing the file stated. However, I would like to parse all of the .xml files in the direcotry. I have tried writing each file into the code like so:

`$twig->parsefile("output_1.xml" "output_2.xml" "output_3.xml");`

And i've also tried using a wildcard like I would in bash like so :

`$twig->parsefile("*.xml");`

But none of these attempts work. How can I change the script so that all of the .xml files in the directory are parsed by the script? I apologise for my lack of knowledge, i've only just started using Perl.

```
#!/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
   twig_handlers => {item => \&acct}
);
$twig->parsefile("output_1.xml");                              

sub acct {
    my ($t, $elt) = @_;

          for my $tag (qw(itemId title viewItemURL convertedCurrentPrice)) {
                    print $elt->field($tag), "\n";
                        }
                            print "\n";
                            print "\n";
                            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enumerate the directory contents as follows:

```
my @files = <*.xml>;    # or: my @files = </your/path/to/*.xml>;
foreach my $file (@files) {
    $twig->parsefile($file);
}
```

Comment: HI thanks, for the response. I tried this and i'm getting the following errors........                       Global symbol "@files" requires explicit package name at testscript.pl line 10.
Global symbol "$file" requires explicit package name at testscript.pl line 11.
Global symbol "@files" requires explicit package name at testscript.pl line 11.
Global symbol "$file" requires explicit package name at testscript.pl line 12.
Execution of testscript.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @bms9nmh I've added "`my`" declarations to prevent these errors. See updated answer.